# How to implement a multithreaded pool in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, file, threadpool

I have a scenario where I use threads.

Firstly I have a folder where there are files which get updated frequently.
So, I wrote a thread which reads the contents of the folder and writes the file names to a static list and updates the list if new files come in.

Secondly i wrote another thread which takes the file names from the list and do some processing with the files.

These two threads run continuously, one checking for new files, one processing the new files.

Now I need to process three files at a time with three threads running. When one thread completes processing another thread takes another file name from the list and starts the process.

So I need some mechanism to have three threads and checking them whether they are alive or not and accordingly starts a new thread and the file list also gets updated frequently.

I also looked into `ExecutorService` but while the list get updated I could not provide it updated list.

Thanks,
Sandeep

Comment: Not very clear, I'm afraid. Why three, and not an arbitrary number? Why check threads to see whether they're alive?

Comment: I meant to add -- it sounds like the natural data structure to use is a queue ( http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html ). To take advantage of this, you would have a consumer thread reading from the queue, doing work when it succeeded in taking items from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building on the existing answers, your code would look something like:

```
    final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

    final FilePoller poller = ...
    final FileProcessor processor = ...

    new Thread(new Runnable() 
      { 
        @Override
        public void run() 
        {
          while (true)
          {
            final File file = poller.pollForFile();
            executor.submit(new Runnable() { public void run() { processor.processFile(file); } } );
          }
        }
      });
```

Assuming your processors can keep up with the poller this would be fine, otherwise you'd want to put in some throttling mechanism before submitting to the executor.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a list; instead use a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor and just drop Runnable's representing the file to be processed into the executor instead of putting them into your global list.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @SimonC's suggestion but instead of a really long comment I have an answer.

```
final FilePoller poller = ...
final FileProcessor processor = ...

final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);

executor.submit(new Runnable() { 
    public void run() {
        final File file = poller.pollForFile();
        executor.submit(new Runnable() { public void run() { processor.processFile(file); } } );
        // repeat, but wait for a free thread.
        executor.submit(this);
    }
  });
 // to stop the whole thing
 executor.shutdown();
```

Answer (score 0):

How about watching for changes in the folder and spawn a thread/file, assuming that the notification change is giving you a list of changes in the folder?